# How do I write parquet tables to SQL Server in databricks?

Tags: sql-server, parquet, azure-databricks

I have parquet files stored in Azure databricks partitioned by timestamps currently. So currently, my files are stored under a folder (call this A) partitioned by different timestamps.

What I want to do is write these parquet files to SQL Server as tables. Is there anyway to do this? I'm using Python.

Comment: can you provide more information - do you want to store different partitions as separate tables? Do you have data in SQL server already?

Comment: I don't already have data in SQL Server. And yes I'd like to store the partitions as separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the standard way to do that - via [JDBC connector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) ([doc for connecting to SQL Server](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#establish-connectivity-to-sql-server)).   You need to extract a list of partitions (4th line is doing that), and iterate over it, filtering data & writing them to the SQL Server.  Something like this:

```py
part_column = 'my_partition_column'
location = 'path_to_files'
df = spark.read.parquet(location)
partitions =[i.name[i.name.index('=')+1:].rstrip('/') for i in dbutils.fs.ls(location) 
    if i.name != '_SUCCESS']
for p in partitions:
  ndf = df.filter(f"{part_column} = '{p}'")
  ndf.write.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort}...") \
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .save()
```